# undefined method for nil:NilClass in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm using RSpec, and I get this error when running tests:

```
 Failure/Error: before { get edit_job_path(job) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `jobs' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:63:in `correct_user'
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:35:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The actual behavior of the page (when doing rails server) seems fine.  Why is the test not working?  I'm still a beginner to Ruby/Rails, so any help would be appreciated.

Some code for help:

**authentication_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do
  subject { page }

  describe "signin" do
    [...]

    describe "authorization" do
      describe "for non-signed in users" do
        describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
          let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
          let(:job) { FactoryGirl.create(:job, user: user) }
          before { get edit_job_path(job) }
          it { should_not have_content('Editing job') }
          describe "after signing in" do
            [...]
          end
          [...]
        end
      end
      [...]
    end
  end
end
```

**jobs_controller.rb**

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:new, :create, :update]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @jobs = Job.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @job = current_user.jobs.build(job_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.save
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.update(job_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @job.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to jobs_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_job
      @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    end

    def job_params
      params.require(:job).permit(:title, :org, :internship, :postdate, :filldate, :location, :link, :description)
    end

    def correct_user
      @job = current_user.jobs.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url, notice: 'You can only edit your own jobs.' if @job.nil?
    end
end
```

**factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Johnny #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "johnny_#{n}@example.com" }
    password "sampleton"
    password_confirmation "sampleton"
  end

  factory :job do
    sequence(:title) { |n| "Example Title #{n}" }
    user
  end
end
```

**sessions_helper.rb**

```
module SessionsHelper
  [...]

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end

  [...]

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
    end
  end

  [...]

  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url if request.get?
  end

  [...]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test seems to be working fine in that they've uncovered a bug. Your action expects that `current_user` be set, and it isn't, so you're getting an error.

You need a `before_filter` which redirects you when you hit a page that requires authorization.

Comment: Yep.  I decided to put a before "before_filter" in the Application Controller and then use "skip_before_filter" for the actions that don't need authentication (whitelist instead of blacklist).